# Breeze metadata can not pick EF Data Annotation

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, data-annotations

I have a model defined with Data Annotations

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(2000,MinimumLength = 300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required,Range(10,500)]
    public int Budget { get; set; }
```

I found out breeze metadata can not pick up the annotation properly for description (minlength) and Budget (range for min and max length). And due to this breeze validation not properly working on client. Here is a breeze metadata for the above model look like

```
property: [
   {
     name: "Id",
     type: "Edm.Int32",
     nullable: "false",
     annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern: "Identity"
   },
   {
     name: "Title",
     type: "Edm.String",
     maxLength: "50",
     fixedLength: "false",
     unicode: "true",
     nullable: "false"
   },
   {
     name: "Description",
     type: "Edm.String",
     maxLength: "300",
     fixedLength: "false",
     unicode: "true",
     nullable: "false"
   },
   {
     name: "Budget",
     type: "Edm.Int32",
     nullable: "false"
   }
]
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently breeze only supports those data annotations that are captured by the Entity Framework CSDL metadata.  This means that only the [Required], [MaxLength] and [MinLength] attributes currently. Of these Breeze only generates client side validations for the [Required] and [MaxLength] attributes. (Missing the MinLength attribute was an oversight on our part that WILL be fixed soon.).

However, with breeze you can, and should, add your own validations directly to the client side model.  See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation.

There is also a [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3899620-support-net-validation-attributes) feature suggestion for this. Please vote for it.

Comment: This is a useful answer but the documentation for that page doesn't appear to mention these.  This is an older post, but it would be nice to have this better called out, as I am currently looking into not having to make custom validators for simple things.  It'd also be nice to know if this differs at all for EFCore